# Using the attribute value from IntegerField in another object attribute

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to learn django, and I am trying to enable image resizing from an image uploaded which is then assigned to an object via admin. I am using the django-stdimage lib.

The idea is an instance as follows can be summoned:

```
class Website_Post(models.Model):
    title                   = models.TextField(default='Enter title')
    intro                   = models.TextField(default='Enter post')
    image_width             = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000), MinValueValidator(0)], default=300)
    image_height            = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000), MinValueValidator(0)], default=300)
    cover = StdImageField(upload_to='images/', 
                  variations={'full': {'width': image_width, 'height': image_height}},null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And then in /admin the image proportions can be defined, with a max value and a min value, which is then applied to the selected image.

My reasoning for this is that the StdImageField variations are not easily accessible once the object has been created, so this way they can adjusted, at least from the backend.

However when running this code, the object cannot be created, as the following error is given:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'IntegerField'
```

with the error at this point:

```
@staticmethod
    def is_smaller(img, variation):
        return img.size[0] > variation['width'] \ # <--- error in this line
            or img.size[1] > variation['height']
```

which to me indicates that the IntegerField value does not appear as an integer when used in the code.

So my question is why is this, and is there a way to resolve this?
Personally, I think the way I have approached this is fundamentally wrong, but I'd like to know where the limitations are.

Answer (score 0):

Error is, `img.size[0]` is integer type value whereas, `variation['width']` is Integer Field. So, you need to convert the Integer Field to int, like:

```
@staticmethod
    def is_smaller(img, variation):
        width = int(variation['width'])
        height = int(variation['height'])
        return img.size[0] >  width or img.size[1] > height
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me, I tried edited both the module code and my code, but am always returned with TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'IntegerField'

Comment: Are you still stuck there?

Comment: Yes, what puzzles me even more is why it doesn't even accept the defaults set, the variable image_width is treated as type 'IntegerField', which is the fundamental problem